# Reference existing AWS environment variables to other env vars

Tags: symfony, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm deploying a Symfony 2.8 application to Elastic Beanstalk and the DB parameters are read from ENV. The EB already has the RDS env set, like RDS_HOSTNAME, RDS_DB_NAME etc, but Symfony needs to read these parameters from env variables prefixed with SYMFONY__. Is there a way to map existing RDS_ variables to the SYMFONY__ ones? I tried with an env.config file placed in the .ebextensions dir, with the following content (sample):

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: SYMFONY__ENV__DATABASE__HOST
    value: "$RDS_HOSTNAME"
```

I know I could duplicate the values in the env.config, but I rather not.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could try `Fn::GetOptionSetting`:

```
option_settings:
  - namespace: aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment
    option_name: SYMFONY__ENV__DATABASE__HOST
    value: 
      "Fn::GetOptionSetting": 
        Namespace: "aws:elasticbeanstalk:application:environment"
        OptionName: "RDS_HOSTNAME"
        DefaultValue: ""
```

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/ebextensions-functions.html#ebextensions-functions-getoptionsetting

Comment: Did this actually work?